# Save html element on API server

Tags: javascript, html, json

hay, looking for a way to use form values and create API site for another app
**like this one**

```
<form class="box" method="post">
      <h1>settings</h1>
      <input type="text" name="" id="color" placeholder="color" value=""/>
      <input  type="submit" name="" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

In javascript you can `document.getElementById("color").value` but i dont get it how should i save information on the server and make json API for another app?

Comment: Like what site? Your 'like this one' is not a link, just bold text. Also, what server-side language/framework are you using?

Comment: That's a form html code, I want to save form values. Server side JSON

Comment: Well, this aint actually javascript related. Depends on the server-sided language you are using.

Comment: Json for api server side